# How to add a follow/unfollow button with node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to this. I am trying to build a website where users can follow/unfollow each other. Like/Unlike posts. 
I am using Node js and MySQL.

I know how to make users add new posts by using a form and this will direct them to a POST route and there I can do the back-end stuff. But how can I add a follow button similar to Twitter/Instagram that changes dynamically when a user clicks on it without refreshing the page.

I thought of something like this in front-end "Profile.ejs file"

```
<form action="/follow" method="POST">
  <input class="btn btn-primary a-btn-slide-text" name="follow" type="submit" value="Follow"/>
</form>
```

But then I am not able to pass in the information for the user I am trying to follow in the back-end (e.g user_id) and not able to change the button value to "unfollow". This is what I thought I would do on the back-end:

```
app.post("/follow", function(req, res){
    var follow = {follower_id:currentUser.id, followee_id:user_id};

    connection.query('INSERT INTO follows SET ?', follow , function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.redirect("/");
    });
});
```

Any idea on how I can achieve this? Also are there any resources/websites/courses that I could learn from on how to use dynamic/javascript stuff like this with nodejs?

Comment: You need to use Ajax, but [What's AJAX??](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started)

Comment: you can create a button follow, than attach to it an onclick event and than do a POST call passing data. If in your frontend you use jquery, see jquery ajax call

Comment: This looks exactly like what I need. Thank you both! I will look more into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Ajax in your front-end template to send a request to your back-end.

Something like that (you don't need to put it in a form):

```
<button type="button" id="follow">Follow</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#follow").click(function(){  
    $.ajax({
       url: '/follow',
       type: 'GET',
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(data, status){ 
           // Here you can change your button text using jQuery
       }
    });
});
</script>
```

Then, in your back-end:

```
app.get("/follow", function(req, res) { 
    var follow = {follower_id:currentUser.id, followee_id:user_id};
    // Do stuff here, call your database, etc.
    res.send({ msg: "User followed/unfollowed!" });
});
```

Your Ajax method will receive this message: `{ msg: "User followed/unfollowed!" }`

Comment: Thank you! I will look more into AJAX as it will help me with other functions on my website.